Data recover made from a HTTP request on json server hosted on Github
I had a problem that I accidentaly overwrote a database in a json server that I have in GitHub but with web services with render, in GitHub I was not able to recover the data, however, through the logs of the deploys in Render I can see the data that was changed through an HTTP request, for example a PUT request with an ID, I can see the ID that was modified but I need to see all the modified data of that ID to try to recover my db with the data that was before my deploy made by github .
Is it possible to see this data?
